# How can I optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables with the follow structure:

```
mysql> describe symbol;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| symbol      | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe price;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_symbol | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date      | date    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price     | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have to query the **price** table to get a list with N prices of two symbols (to compare them)

This is a sample result:

```
DATE        SYMBOL 1 SYMBOL 2
2011-01-01    100      23
2011-01-02    92       26
2011-01-03    89       50
```

So I need to find the same data of both and return their prices.
I have created a query that seem it does the job, but maybe is not very optimized.

```
SELECT *
FROM price AS a
  JOIN price AS b ON a.date = b.date
WHERE a.id_symbol = 1 AND b.id_symbol = 2
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

What do you think?

Can I optimize the query doing something (or maybe change something on the tables structure)?

**EDIT:**

This is the result of the EXPLAIN {query}

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT *
    -> FROM price AS a
    ->   JOIN price AS b ON a.date = b.date
    -> WHERE a.id_symbol = 1 AND b.id_symbol = 2
    -> ORDER BY a.date DESC
    -> LIMIT 100;
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | date,id_symbol | id_symbol | 4       | const |  921 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | date,id_symbol | id_symbol | 4       | const |  966 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

What do you think?

> Then... what is 921 and 966 on the EXPLAIN "ROW" column ? If i count
>   the prices i have for symbol 1 and symbol 2 i get: 912 and 912 :-| what is
>   that?

(P.S. Yes, my mistake i have to change * with the columns i want)

Comment: "Not very optimized" ? What's the problem?

Comment: Don't you want to specify columns not use `select *`?

Comment: Apart from replacing `*` with just the columns you need there is not much to do in the query. Have you created relevant indexes? Is it slow? How slow, any execution plan? Can you post the result of [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)?

Comment: Why anyone gave this a +1 bazzles me. It perfectly matches the "there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”" from the FAQ

Comment: I've added EXPLAIN result, take a look above.

Answer (score 1):

based on the limited info, about all you can do is create an index on `id_symbol ASC, date DESC` and possibly limit the `*` to only the columns you need.

Your biggest "speed up" may be to combine your two queries into a single one and then just run that one query and parse the result set instead of running one query to get all the symbol pairs and then a different query for each symbol pair.  You don't provide the original query, so it is impossible to suggest this combined query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT *
FROM price AS a
JOIN price AS b ON a.date = b.date
WHERE a.id_symbol = 1 AND b.id_symbol = 2
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

You need to make two major changes:

**CHANGE #1 : REFACTOR YOUR QUERY**

Using only keys, make WHEREs, ORDER BYs happen first, JOINs last

```
SELECT A.date,GROUP_CONCAT(A.price ORDER BY A.id_symbol) prices
FROM price A
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT BB.* FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT date FROM
    (
       SELECT AAAA.date FROM
       (SELECT date FROM price WHERE id_symbol = 1) AAAA
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT date FROM price WHERE id_symbol = 2) BBBB
       USING (date)
       ORDER BY AAAA.date
    ) AAA ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100
  ) AA
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT date,id_symbol FROM price WHERE id_symbol in (1,2)) BB
  USING (date)
  ORDER BY BB.date DESC,BB.id_symbol
) B
USING (date,id_symbol) GROUP BY date;
```

**CHANGE #2 : CREATE INDEX TO SUPPORT THE REFACTORED QUERY**

```
ALTER TABLE price ADD INDEX symbol_date_id_ndx (id_symbol,date,id);
ALTER TABLE price ADD INDEX date_id_ndx (date,symbol_id);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Rolando thank you so much for your answer. Only one thing, why you added "id" to symbol_date_id_ndx ?id_symbol and date are useful, what about "id"?

Comment: Putting all the necessary fields in the index obliges the MySQL Query Optimizer to get the needed data from the index only. This is known as an index scan. This comes from the concept known as covering indexes : See http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html , http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/ , and http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/ for more info on when , how, and why to create or not create covering indexes.

Comment: Rolando, do i have to remove the previous indexes I have created (id_symbol, date)? thank you

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'B USING (id)' at line 1

Comment: Yes, remove the (id_symbol,date) index abd replace it with (id_symbol,date,id) index.

Comment: Rolando, what big type? i see ORDER "BT"...btw i0m tring the query, thank you!

Comment: Nothing, I get "empty set" but it is too strange if i check it with my query all works good.

Comment: @Dail let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2677/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-dail)

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the perhaps very appropriate comments about premature optimization, have you tried using EXPLAIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) to see how your query is actually executed?  From there you may want to look into adding indexes.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is an answer.

Comment: I've added EXPLAIN result, take a look above.